# How to reduce reserved RUs to reduce cost of DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azureportal

We are using DocumentDB on azure. We have a single database with 7 collection, each having maximum 15 records. It does not require much storage.

Only a few developers are using this DB instance. So traffic is also below average.

Still this server is using 67,600 RUs per day. There must be some problem with DocumentDB settings. So, I'm looking for direction to analyse exactly how these RUs are charged and how to reduce it?

Comment: From what you've described, you don't need to use DocumentDB. You could migrate the small amount of data you have over to Azure Table Storage and use that instead, or even a small Azure SQL Database. Azure Table Storage would give you the cheapest option by far.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann I don't see how that comment is relevant in this case. We have no knowledge of the OP's plans, or specific needs for a document store vs relational or key/value. There are *always* alternatives. But the question was specific to DocumentDB (and the need to understand the docdb Collection model, given the original parameters presented).

Comment: @DavidMakogon Since the question was about reducing cost, it seemed appropriate to mention one valid option that may provide a significant cost savings rather than just reconfiguring usage of the same service. Also, that's why it was posted as a Comment; not an Answer.

Comment: @ChrisPietschmann, thanks. As DocumentDB does not allow to reduce reserved resources below 400, now I'm looking into alternative for DocumentDB as you suggested.

Comment: @DhairyaVora np, you may be able to use a small Azure SQL Database as well, depending on your needs

Answer (score 6):

There's no problem with DocumentDB settings. You provisioned 7 collections. By default, via the portal, each collection is assigned 1000 RU (which you have at your disposal, regardless whether you use 0 RU or all 1000 RU). The minimum RU setting for a non-partitioned collection is 400.

**EDIT** - I misread - if you're at 67,000 RU, then you have likely provisioned several *partitioned* collections (which start at 10,100 RU). For initial dev/test, with only 15 documents, you've *grossly over-allocated* capacity.

Since you provisioned seven collections (which are likely partitioned, based on your RU sizing), you have a ~70,000 RU deployment. Regardless what you actually consume (you're essentially reserving capacity).

I have no idea what your app needs are, and whether you need 7 collections for some specific reason. But... objectively speaking, there is no rule that says you need to separate different document types into different collections. You can easily store heterogeneous data within a single collection. How you query for specific types is really up to you, but it's trivial to add something like a `type` property to each document).

Note, since I now believe you're using partitioned collections: You cannot convert these to non-partitioned collections; you'll need to create new non-partitioned collections and move your data from your partitioned collections. (given that you have 15 total documents, this should be trivial).

Note that a single non-partitioned collection may be scaled down to 400 RU. If you then combine your 7 collections into 1 collection, you should be able to reduce your consumption from ~70,000 => 400. (at least during dev/test).

**EDIT** As of February 2017, the minimum RU for partitioned collections dropped to 2,500 (from the original 10,100 minimum). In December 2017, it dropped again, to 1,000.

Comment: So you are suggesting that we should combine all 7 collections into 1 collection and set "type" property with each record. I understand that this can reduce number of collections and hence reduce the cost of Reserved Units. Meanwhile if there is still a way to reduce reserved units, kindly let me know. Also is there a way to analyse exact numbers of RU used against each collection for last hour/24hours/week to confirm our assumption of above calculations?

Comment: I gave you all the info you need, to make an informed decision how to reduce your RU and related costs. I really can't make any specific decisions for you - I know nothing about your app or needs, but you now know the minimum RU settings for both non-partitioned and partitioned collections, and can decide what to change or combine, accordingly. As for analysis, that's a completely separate question (and new questions shouldn't be placed in comments).

Comment: for anyone facing similar problem in future, reducing to single collection helped controlling cost drastically. I had to add an extra property for differentiating records because all records are in single collection.

Comment: @DhairyaVora - if this took care of your issue, you should consider voting/marking as an answer, so that this question can be properly closed out.

Comment: I think you **heavily misread the OP**. The reserved RUs are per second. 67600 RU per day is 2816 RU per hour or 47 RU per minute or 0.8 RU per second

Comment: @Tseng - I actually diagnosed the OP's issue exactly. There is no such thing as RU-per-day. You may only allocate RU on a per-second basis (and then that's billed hourly). And there's absolutely no way to have a per-second rate of less than 400 RU (or 1000 RU for partitioned collections). Note: the only thing off, in my answer: the minimum RU for partitioned collections has dropped again, to 1,000 (from 2,500). The OP's question should have just read "67,600 RU" and left off the "per day" part.

Answer (score 4):

It's common for people new to DocumentDB to think of a collection similar to a table in SQL or even what MongoDB calls a "collection". However, DocumentDB is designed differently. It's best to use a single partitioned collection to store all document types and partition on something like geography, tenant, or user. You'll distinguish document types with a `type = <MyType>` field or I actually prefer to use `myType = true` approach so I can model inheritance and mixins.

This means, you'll only need to pay for a single partitioned collection. A single partitioned collection may still end up costing you more than table storage, but if you want DocumentDB's near infinite scalability later on, then I highly recommend you start out the way I'm describing.

One more note about David's suggestion to go with non-partitioned collections. That was the only option when DocumentDB first launched but it's now recommended to use partitioned collections. I suspect that non-partitioned collection option may be phased out at some point. You interact with them slightly differently and as David pointed out, there is currently no conversion assistance (especially if you use multiple non-partitioned collections) so transitioning later from non-partitioned collections to a partitioned collection is not hard but it's not as simple as changing your partition type and will cost you development effort. It'll cost you a little more to have a single partitioned collection than a single non-partitioned collection, but it's worth it to save transition costs later, IMHO and it'll cost you less to have a single partitioned collection than it costs to have seven non-partitioned ones.